# Microsoft Graph online meeting created through API not showing on Teams application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have implemented Teams graph api in my project where I am creating Online meetings.

Getting success JSON output 
[image]

But the same i cannot see in Teams windows application.

Payload passing to POST method
[image]

Comment: Could you please tell us which team API you are using to create online meeting, if you are using [Create Online Meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). The meeting does not show up on the user's calendar.

Comment: Yes I am using the same api [Create Online Meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: So is there any options available to show the meetings in application ?

Comment: I don't think so but if you are looking for creating a meeting invite, I would suggest you to go with [Create Event using Online Meeting Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-5-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting) API.which shows up in users calendar as well you will get the joinWebUrl too,

Comment: Okay thanks for the help @Trinetra-MSFT. I'll check